# Best practices frame title

Tags: beamer

When building a presentation using beamer...

The following two commands seem to do the same thing, is there an advantage of one over the other? What is best practice?

**Option 1**

```
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\end{frame}
```

**Option 2**

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! I strongly prefer option 2 because I have seen to many things going wrong with option 1. Things like the following are IMHO less cryptic: `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{[hello]}

\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: I saw some question that was entirely triggered by the shorter syntax yielding some unexpected result, but I cannot find it any more. :-( Another example that suggests to use `\frametitle`: `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{[hello]}
\frametitle<2>{[hello world]}

\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made this answer a community Wiki, hoping others will add more examples. My opinion is

> use `\frametitle

Why? The beamer manual says about the frame environment

[image]

So you see that it is a very "rich" environment in the sense that you have tons of option. That is, even though you can pass the title to the `\begin{frame}` command, you need to take a lot of care not to screw up things. Also most of the examples in the manual use `\frametitle`. An explicit example of something that is easier to handle with the `\frametitle` command is

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
 \frametitle<1>{[hello]} 
 \frametitle<2>{[hello world]} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Another conceivable advantage of explicit `\frametitle`s is that you can search for titles more easily in your document.